# JS Cache API: Cached Images served by Google Cloud Bucket don't load

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, cacheapi

I'm writing a web app, where the user can download images for a later offline usage using the Cache API.

```
// when the user clicks the download button
window.caches.open("imageCache").then(function(cache) {
          cache.add(imageUrls)
              .then(() => console.log("image cached"))
              .catch((e) => console.error(e));
      });
```

This works as expected. Using the Chrome-Developer-Tools (under Application -> Cache Storage) I see the list of images:

[image]

Now, when I want to display the images in offline-mode using simple `img`-Tags, it does not work for images that are served from a Google Cloud Bucket, but it does work with other image-sources.

**Image from Google Cloud Buckets fails to load in offline mode:**

[image]

**Image from fakeimg.pl shows up in offline mode:**

[image]

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Image are not at all clear.

Comment: @RajeshG Sorry, added them in full size now.

Comment: May be due to Cache control set not-transform for google images.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit in this case was `vary: Origin`. But I noticed that Chrome seems to be the only browser that makes use of images that are cached with the Cache API **without** using a service worker anyway.

So I implemented a service-worker with workbox now and it works.